# React Native - Dimensions.get("window").height is not the same on different android devices

Tags: android, react-native, android-layout, user-interface, layout

I'm trying to keep the layout height to be the same on different devices

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

class App extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {

        let height = Dimensions.get("window").height;

        let box1_height = height - 128;
        let box2_height = 64;
        let box3_height = 64;


        return <>
            <View style={{ height: box1_height, backgroundColor: "blue" }}></View>
            <View style={{ height: box2_height, backgroundColor: "red" }}></View>
            <View style={{ height: box3_height, backgroundColor: "green" }}></View>
        </>
    }
}

export default App;
```

And this is how it looks on my Galaxy S7 device:

[image]

As you can see, The red and the green box got the same height

But on my Pixel 7 device, there is a white gap under the green box:

[image]

I added **box1_height + StatusBar.currentHeight**

It fixed the white gap on Pixel 7 device

but the green box moved down on Galaxy s7

[image]

How do I keep the layout to be the same on different devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need an exact height for the blue part, you can use flexbox like this:

```
  <View style={{ flex:1, backgroundColor: "blue" }}></View>
  <View style={{ height: box2_height, backgroundColor: "red" }}></View>
  <View style={{ height: box3_height, backgroundColor: "green" }}></View>
```

the blue part will fill all the available space and the red and green ones will keep their size